# Documentation for Python with company

Tags: python, company-mode, documentation

I'm using Emacs with company and company-quickhelp. This works fine for Elisp and Clojure.
However, displaying the quickhelp popup (or function signature) in Python mode doesn't work. I installed company-jedi and have the following settings in my `~/.emacs.d/init.el`

```el
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
(company-quickhelp-mode 1)

(defun my/python-mode-hook ()
(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-jedi))

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'my/python-mode-hook)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'run-python-internal)
```

The quickhelp popup doesn't show and after pressing F1 the minibuffer says "No documentation available". What am I missing?

Comment: What is the value of `company-backends` in a python buffer? My guess is that company-jedi is already in the list, in which case `(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-jedi)` does nothing. This matters because `company-complete` calls the first eligible back end in the list. Thus if (e.g.) `company-capf` comes before `company-jedi` you would get the behavior you describe.

Comment: @Ista It's value is `(company-jedi company-bbdb company-nxml company-css company-eclim company-semantic company-clang company-xcode company-cmake company-capf
              (company-dabbrev-code company-gtags company-etags company-keywords)
              company-oddmuse company-files company-dabbrev)` and after removing `(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-jedi))` completion in Python buffers doesn't work at all. It's basically copied from https://github.com/syohex/emacs-company-jedi

Comment: It seems there is an issue about this behavior https://github.com/syohex/emacs-company-jedi/issues/2 but it is still not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in `jedi-core` `20150528.2022` from MELPA (https://github.com/syohex/emacs-company-jedi/issues/2). After updating to `20150611.254` displaying the function signature works as expected.

[image: company-jedi example]